# Remove trailing slash in home page url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If my website is

http://www[dot]abc[dot]com/

and if somebody types like

http://www[dot]abc[dot]com/////////////

then I want to redirect it to

http://www[dot]abc[dot]com/

can anyone help me to redirect this....when I tried I got this message "this web page has too many redirect"

Answer (score 1):

For home page only:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+$
RewriteRule * http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

or just:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+$
RewriteRule * / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you should have a look on mod_rewrite.
It should suffice to put this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/+$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```